# Passing a Fabric env.host string as a variable

Tags: python, cloud-hosting, fabric

I want to be able to programmatically create a new cloud server, and then pass the new root@1.2.3.4 into additional Fabric commands to run other setup scripts.

I am able to create the server, grab the relevant variables, and initiate a local('ssh root@1.2.3.4') command to add the new IP to my known hosts file.  However, regardless of however I try to pass the string 'root@1.2.3.4' to Fabric, it still presents me with:

> No hosts found. Please specify (single) host string for connection:

I have tried all sorts of string manipulation, such as:

> env.host = '%s' % host
>
> env.hosts = [host]
>
> env.host = str(host)

However, Fabric always presents me with the "No hosts found" prompt.  If I copy and paste the result of 'print host', that works fine.  Granted, not a huge hurdle but really breaks down the whole auto-rollout approach I am trying to take.

Has anyone been successful in passing a env.host/hosts declaration to Fabric using a variable?

Answer (score 0):

The "No hosts found" error is a bit deceptive. It throws if what you've put in `env.hosts` isn't well formed. `env.hosts` should look something like one of these:

```
env.hosts = ['1.2.3.4']
env.hosts = ['1.2.3.4', 'hostname', '4.5.6.7']
```

It should *not* include the user (`root@1.2.3.4`) that gets passed to `env.user`

Try something like this:

```
h = '1.2.3.4'
env.hosts = [h]
```